# React Native cannot connect to localhost from another device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, django-rest-framework, localhost

I use Django rest framework as my API, however, I'm unable to connect to localhost from my android device (not an emulator). I have gone through many questions on StackOverflow and Github but none worked

here is my code

```
import { create } from 'apisauce';

const apiClient = create({
    baseURL: 'http://tried-many-things-but-none-worked:8000',
});
// getting data is straight forward
import client from './client';
const getChat = id => client.get("/chat/get_chat/${id}/";
```

I tried many solutions but none worked for me. I tried using

- 10.0.2.2 but it worked for AVD only,
- 10.0.3.2 worked for Genymotion only.
- localhost and 127.0.0.1 worked only in POSTMAN.
- also tried using the machine IP address but it keeps loading forever, I tried to wait for it to finish loading to end up with an error in both POSTMAN and my React Native app

And nothing worked for my external device! I would really appreciate any helpÏ

Please note that the problem isn't with the code as I tried to upload it to pythonanywhere web hosting service and used the URL I got from them and it was working fine with no errors (as well as from postman and the emulator)

Extra information: pc: macOS High Sierra version: 10.13.6, external device: Android

Comment: shouldn't it be `apiClient.get("/chat/get_chat/${id}/";`??

Comment: by doing "import client from './client';" I can use "client" as "apiClient", I tested it after hosting my website and it worked fine. and Vscode IntelliSense is working for it

Comment: You should use the lan ip of your pc. Try this ip in a browser on your Android device too. Switch of the firewall of that pc. Be shure your server is not bound to fixed ips but accepts from all incoming ips.

Comment: Your Android device is its own localhost. Every device is its own localhost. Not only your pc.

Comment: `localhost and 127.0.0.1 worked only in POSTMAN.` If so, then you did that on your pc. It would not have worked on your Android device.

Comment: `to end up with an error in both POSTMAN and my React Native app` Why not tell us the exact error? And you used postman on pc?

Comment: Yes postman and the emulator where used on the same device and that's why they worked. However on a different device (my android phone) it doesn't work, the error is NETWORK_ERROR. and is the plan IP address different from the machine IP address I get from this google search https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip+address&rlz=1C5CHFA_enEG924EG924&oq=what+is+my+ip+address&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i67j0i20i263j0l5.3680j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I just checked my system preference and the firewall is turned off,
 for my server I just typed "Python3 manage.py runserver" and let Django handle the rest so I'm not sure how I can check the "ips allowed" from my server.

Comment: I told you to use the local lan ip of your pc. Not the public ip of your router.  And to know what your server does you can dive in its python code i think...

Comment: I tried with my local ip address but it still doesn't work, In postman it refuses to make a connection "Could not send request" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ngrok** for this. You will get a new domain name from ngrok instead playing with localhost/ip etc.
You can check this documentation for more info https://ngrok.com/docs